# Groups and counts data based on year of a Date field

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lodash

I've this dataset:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
]
```

it's basically an array of objects. Each object contains a field `date` with an Date Object.

What I would like to have is this:

```js
const result = {
  cat: {2020: 1, 2021: 2},
  dog: {2020: 1, 2021: 2},
  hamster: {2019: 1},
  't-rex': {2019: 1, 2020: 1},
  sheep: {2019: 2},
}
```

So an objects grouped by `animal` and each animal value is an object whose contains a key for each year and the value is the number of records with that years.

As you can see, `cat` has 2 dates in 2021 and 1 in 2020 so `cat: {2020: 1, 2021: 2}`.

I think I can use [d3.rollup](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#rollup) and do something like:

```js
const result = d3.rollup(data, v => v.?, d => d.animal)
```

I don't know how to use, or maybe there is a smarter solution, I can use also Lodash.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved thanks to @georg answer!

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, 
]

const rolled = d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, v => v.animal, v => v.date.getFullYear())
const result = Array.from(rolled).reduce((acc, r) => {
  acc[r[0]] = Object.fromEntries(r[1])
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed easy with `d3.rollup`:

```
result = d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, v => v.animal, v => v.date.getFullYear())
```

this gives you nested `Map`s, if you want objects for some reason, convert the maps like this:

```
objects = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(result, ([k, v]) => 
        [k, Object.fromEntries(v)]))
```

If you don't want the d3 dependency, you can rewrite `rollup` in vanilla JS:

```
function rollup(data, reducer, grouper, ...groupers) {
    let m = new Map

    if (!grouper)
        return reducer(data)

    for (let item of data) {
        let key = grouper(item)
        m.has(key) ? m.get(key).push(item) : m.set(key, [item])
    }

    for (let [k, v] of m)
        m.set(k, rollup(v, reducer, ...groupers))

    return m
}
```

And finally, if you're looking for plain and fast code rather than "smart" one, you can simply iterate once and populate the nested object directly (this is where the [nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) `??=` comes in handy):

```
const result = {}

for (let obj of data) {
    let k1 = obj.animal,
        k2 = obj.date.getFullYear()

    result[k1] ??= {}
    result[k1][k2] ??= 0
    result[k1][k2]++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const data = [
  { animal: "cat", name: "mu", date: new Date(2020, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "cat", name: "muji", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "cat", name: "mine", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "dog", name: "fido", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "dog", name: "fido2", date: new Date(2020, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "dog", name: "fido3", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "hamster", name: "gerry", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "t-rex", name: "dino", date: new Date(2020, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "t-rex", name: "sauro", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "sheep", name: "s", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1) },
  { animal: "sheep", name: "sss", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1) },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { animal, date } = curr;
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  if (acc[animal]) {
    acc[animal][year] ? ++acc[animal][year] : (acc[animal][year] = 1);
  } else {
    acc[animal] = {
      [year]: 1,
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the result object with `Object.fromEntries`, so it has the keys, but with an empty object associated with each. Then populate those objects as you iterate the data:

```js
const data = [{animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, ];

let res = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({animal}) => [animal, {}]));
for (let {animal, date} of data) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    res[animal][year] = (res[animal][year]??0) + 1;
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash you can group by the `animal` property, and then map the groups using `_.mapValues()`, and use `_.countBy()` to count the number of appearances of each year:

```js
const data = [{animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, ];

const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(data, 'animal'),
  group => _.countBy(group, o => o.date.getFullYear())
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And the same idea using lodash/fp:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, mapValues, countBy } = _

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy('animal'),
  mapValues(countBy(o => o.date.getFullYear()))
)

const data = [{animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)},{animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1)},{animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)},{animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1)}, ];

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```